# Codeigniter form_validation does not validate

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, authentication

I'm currently working on my login form. Yesterday when I logged in, even though the credentials are wrong it logs me in so I changed the `=` to `==` of this code in my model.

```
public function can_log_in() {

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
    $data1 = array(
        'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
    );
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data1);

    if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now even if the credentials are right it doesnt log-in. Here are my controllers:

```
public function loginValidate() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('USERNAME','Username','required|trim|callback_validateCreds');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PASSWORD','Password','required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('login/adminIndex'); 
    }
}

public function validateCreds() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    if($this->login_model->can_log_in()) { // can_log_in() model
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validateCreds','Username and password did not match.');  //return message to validateCreds

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually the password is encrypted,Did you consider?

Comment: yes. i just took the encryption off so that it will be easier for me to find out whether there's an error or the creds are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Problem Model function near `if($query->num_rows==1)`

you change like this `if($query->num_rows()==1)`

full code in model function

```
public function can_log_in(){

$sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
$data1 = array(
    'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
    'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
    );

$this->db
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $data1);


if ($query->num_rows() == 1){

    return true;

}else{

    return false;
}
```